# Using System.Device.Location in asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, .net, location

What coordinates I can get using System.Device.Location namespace in my asp.net app? Is it coordinates of a server the site is running on? What if my app is running in the cloud?

Comment: "What if my app is running in the cloud?" -> It gets you the address of the "cloud server" (physical machine, VM, container) running your application.

Comment: If that's the case what would be a reason for Position.Location.IsUnknown when the app runs in Azure?

Comment: System.Device.Location works based on the machine that the app is running on. It knows nothing about the web. If you want to get a web application client's location, then you need to look into what capabilities are exposed by the browser. It's a client side detail.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) say "the System.Device.Location classes are fully functional if a location provider is installed and can determine the computer's location", so if the location provider is missing, that gets you `Position.Location.IsUnkown`...